# How to create custom function in default.vcl within Varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have repetitive code in my vcl and I want to create custom function without embedding inline C code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a custom subroutine like this

```
sub my_subroutine {
  ... 
}
```

and call it like this:

```
call my_subroutine;
```

From: http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Basics.html

> Subroutines in VCL take neither arguments nor return values. Each
>   subroutine terminates by calling return (action), where action is a
>   keyword that indicates the desired outcome. Subroutines may inspect
>   and manipulate HTTP header fields and various other aspects of each
>   request. Subroutines instruct how requests are handled.
>
> Subroutine example:
>
> sub pipe_if_local {   if (client.ip ~ local) {
>       return (pipe);   } }
>
> To call a subroutine, use the call keyword followed by the
>   subroutine’s name:
>
> call pipe_if_local;
>
> Varnish has built-in subroutines that are hook into the Varnish
>   workflow. These built-in subroutines are all named vcl_*. Your own
>   subroutines cannot start their name with vcl_.